# Автоматическое обновление сущностей в Java-коде при database first подходе

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, orm, pojo

Есть ли фреймворк или библиотека, которые могут автоматически создавать и **обновлять** клиентское представление модели БД? Т.е. при изменении мною схемы в БД (добавил ли я например вручную новую таблицу в БД или новое поле в таблице или создал новую связь между таблицами) автоматически обновлялось Java-представление модели БД (на этапе разработки), чтобы мне не создавать или изменять сущности в Java-коде вручную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно копать в сторону плагинов для вашей среды разработки. Удастся ли найти что-то подходящее, будет зависеть как от самой среды (тут у Idea преимущество, но она платная) , так и от используемой базы данных. Не для каждой базы есть плагины для построения моделей.

Выглядит это обычно как-то так:

[image: Плагин для создания модели по таблице БД]

Сразу признаюсь, что лично для себя я подходящего плагина не нашёл и пилю модельки руками.

На счёт **обновлять**, не перегибайте палку. Найти бы, чтобы генерировало, уж обновить-то не проблема (сгенерировать заново -- делов на полминуты).